# HTML doesn't update visually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xampp

So this is really strange and I don't know how to really describe it but my HTML code stopped updating visually after I moved to XAMPP.

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<p class="selector">click me to change #indicator</p>
<p id="indicator">1</p>
```

```js
$(".selector").click(function() {
    $("#indicator").text("2");
}
```

So when i press the button it just doesn't update visually (on the HTML side) only becouse if I run `$("#indicator).text()` it outputs `2`. The problem started when I moved to XAMPP, also my website with all its files (CSS, JS, HTML, PHP) weights aroud 4.2MB so that could be the case I suppose? Any ideas why?

Edit:
`document.getElementById("indicator").innerHTML` also returns `2` so that's not jQuery's problem/

Comment: Probably Cache issue, hard reload page (ctrl+shift+r) and it should work.

Comment: you need to close your jquery function properly (with a round bracket)

Comment: try to look at the timestamp of the file and compare if it looks right when you last edited it